# resize a window bases on the text content

Tags: java, swing, text, resize

I want to be able to Enter Text that will appear on the window and then if I were to re-size the window then the text could change with its size. The problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to implement this. Since I will to writing to the Jpanel I'm thinking I would have to use a Jlabel to add the text onto the window, but then resizing the window might not affect the Jlabel? Am I suppose to directly write on the Jpanel somehow, or get the size of the window(length and width) and use that to increase or decrease the size of the text? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly that you are trying to re-size some label type text you could try something along these lines:

```
public class ResizeTextTest extends JFrame{
public ResizeTextTest() {
    add(new MyPanel());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResizeTextTest t = new ResizeTextTest();
    t.setSize(400,300);
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    t.setVisible(true);
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Using a multiplier like this on the width and height of the
        //Panel will give you a text size that correlates with the size
        //of the window.
        Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 
                (int) (.0005 * this.getWidth() * this.getHeight()));
        g.setFont(f);
        g.drawString("Hello World", 50, 100);

    }
}
```

The paintComponent method is automatically called when the window is resized. You can also call it explicitly using the component's repaint() method.

Comment: This is exactly what my question was asking but I have a question. When I try to resize the window by decreasing the width it stops at the end the Hello Word, which is exactly what i'm looking for, but if I decrease the height it hides the Hellow Word. Is it possible to stop the height once the text is reached?

Comment: Also how did you know the .0005 as the multiplier? Thanks

Comment: The java.awt.FontMetrics class has methods that you can use to return the height or width of a given string. You can instantiate an object of FontMetrics using the getFontMetrics() method in the Graphics class. Once you have the height of the string just perform a check to make sure that the starting y-Coordinate minus the string's height is not less than zero, and if it is set the starting y-Coordinate to 0.
In answer to your second question I didn't know to use .0005 as a multiplier, I just used steadily decreasing numbers until I found one that seemed to fit the panel well.

Comment: I made had a small typo in the last comment. If the check shows that the y-Coordinate minus the string's height is less than 0 you need to set the y-coordinate to the string's height, not to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [text area](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), not a label. Make sure the 'line wrap' property is selected/true.